# how to invoke SQL inside perl script

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, unix

I am trying to connect with database and perform some SQL queries by using this code, but every time it hangs.

```
my $connect_str = `/osp/local/etc/.oralgn $srv_name PSMF`;
my $sqlFile = "/osp/local/home/linus/amit/mytest.sql";
my ($abc, $cde)= split (/\@/ , $connect_str );
print "$abc";

$ORACLE_SID=SDDG00;
`export $ORACLE_SID`;

#chomp($abc);

#$abc=~ s/\s+$//;
`sqlplus $abc`;

open (SQL, "$sqlFile");


while (my $sqlStatement = <SQL>) {
   $sth = dbi->prepare($sqlStatement)
         or die (qq(Can't prepare $sqlStatement));

            $sth->execute()
                  or die qq(Can't execute $sqlStatement);
                  }
```

How do I invoke a SQL command inside `Perl`?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [documentation for the DBI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) would be a good start.

Your problem seems to be this line.

```
$sth = dbi->prepare($sqlStatement)
```

You're trying to call the `prepare` method on the class "dbi". But you don't have a class called "dbi" in your program (or, at least, I can't see one in the code you've shown us).

To use a database from Perl you need to do these things:

1/ Load the DBI module (note, "DBI", not "dbi" - Perl is case sensitive).

```
use DBI;
```

2/ Connect to the database and get a database handle (Read the [DBD::Oracle documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle) for more details on the arguments to the `connect()` method).

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:dbname', $user, $password);
```

3/ You can then use this database handle to prepare SQL statements.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlStatement);
```